# Even distribute divs with a fixed size

Tags: html, css

I went through a couple of similar questions but the answers didn't work for me.

I have several divs, and each of them has a fixed width of 210px.

The container they're in can resize depending on the screen size of the user. The divs have to be evenly spaced horizontally at all time and it should also break the line of divs into another line if there is no space.

To clear things up more, refer the figure below.
[image]

This [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvgn46hu/1/) has achieved the outcome I want. But I can't see how it'll work for my divs which must have a fixed width.

```
width: calc(100% / 6);
```

EDIT:

The problem with the JS Fiddle is that when the screen size is where it has space, but not enough space to fit another div. In which case, the last div should be closer to the right.

[image]

Comment: Flexbox to the rescue.

Comment: Why Flexbox? Inline-Block, static width, percentage gutter.

Comment: @MarcoHengstenberg Ah.. percentage gutter!

Comment: flex box can help to fill entire lines setting a min-width to the child, but no too close to question i believe: http://jsfiddle.net/bvgn46hu/108/ interesting fallback somehow to what wished in first place

Comment: What about changing the div's width to fixed size in the fiddle you provided? http://jsfiddle.net/0tc8e0kf/

Comment: @sc3w Hi. I edited the question and added the part why the JS fiddle didn't work.

Comment: @user3607282 can you change HTML structure?

Comment: @NenadVracar How should it be structured?

Comment: you may then use text-align:justify and a pseudo to mimic the justify-content:space-between from flex if you want to stick to inline-block http://jsfiddle.net/bvgn46hu/114/ but i really like better my earlier proposal ;) no big wholes ... http://jsfiddle.net/bvgn46hu/108/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) can do what you want by setting `justify-content` to `space-around` (or `space-between`, depending on your presentational needs). Here's a quick example:

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-around;
  margin:0;
  padding:5px;
}
div{
  background:#000;
  flex:0 0 210px;
  height:210px;
  margin:5px;
  width:210px;
}
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

Check [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for details on browser support and prefixing.

Comment: Generally correct depending on how the OP wants the boxes on the last line to appear.

Comment: Darn, I really need to take the time to get comfortable using flex-box. Seems like it will save writing a ton of extra code for common design patterns like this.

Comment: This is a very good beginner tutorial on flexbox and its properties: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Agreed, @Paulie_D, but there are other questions on SO dealing with that issue.

Answer (score 0):

http://kyusuf.com/post/almost-complete-guide-to-flexbox-without-flexbox

So here is an article explaining how to achieve visual layouts without using Flexbox (which comes with a lot of bugs and you would have to dive in deep to make it work across browsers consistently – browser support gets worse when you don't tinker with the syntax on top of it, so let's assume:"There is no Flexbox!").

The solution to your problem at hand would be pretty straight forward without Flexbox:

```
.container {
  padding: y%; /* by giving the container a percentage based padding, you will create a slowly upscaling container as screen-width increases */
}

.box {
  width: 210px; /* whyever they need a fixed width but ok, who knows */
  margin-right: x%; /* x should be replaced with a value that distributes your containers evenly across the screen and makes them wrap when needed. Fiddle with the value until it makes sense to you. */
}
```

Does that solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If i refer to screen shot and everyone idea, flexbox is here to help you (I was expecting feed back from my comments actually about http://jsfiddle.net/bvgn46hu/108/ & http://jsfiddle.net/bvgn46hu/114/ )

```css
#container {
  margin:1em;
  color:turquoise;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  border: solid;
  padding:2vh;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
#container > div:before {
  content:'boxe ';
  padding-right:0.25em;;
}
#container > div {
  display:flex;
  
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  min-height:25vh;
  border: solid;
  margin:1vh 0;
  width:400px;
  min-width:calc(100vw  / 4);
  max-width: 45%;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

[codepen to play with](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EKeEQZ)